# Installing pypy on conda environ - cuda driver error

Tags: python, conda, pypy

Following the instructions from [here](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/), i'm getting a cuda driver error that i can't make sense off.

Does anyone know how i can resolve this?

Thanks in advance

```
(pypy) C:\Users\pamci>conda activate pypy

(pypy) C:\Users\pamci>conda install pypy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pypy -> python==3.6.9[build='0_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|1_73_pypy']

Your python: python=3.6.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0

Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

'''

Comment: Before you get to the CUDA driver, you need to solve your Python version error, indicated by these lines: `pypy -> python==3.6.9[build='0_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|1_73_pypy']`

Comment: @james, forgive me but how do i read that part of the error? it says i should have python==3.6.9 but i have python 3.6.9 install for that environ? i'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPy is not yet available via conda for the windows platform.

Comment: do you know of a guide to install it outside of conda? i was running into an error with that as well. keep failing at the ensurepip stage.

Comment: C:\Users\pamci\pypy>pypy3.exe -m ensurepip
Looking in links: c:\Users\pamci\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbxxrrs1f
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\pamci\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\site-packages (50.3.2)
WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\pamci\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\pamci\\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32\\site-packages\\setuptools-50.3.2.dist-info\\METADATA'

Comment: Why is pypy llooking in a %TEMP% directory? Do you have any of PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH set (you should not set them)?

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you did to get that message? You uzipped the downloaded file and then ...?

Comment: i unzipped the pypy3.7 file for windows, edited environment vairable PATH to point at the folder that i have just unzipped. then the above commands. @mattip

Comment: What does `>set PY` show? Do you have any `PYTHON` environment variables set?

Comment: it returns this: PyCharm Community Edition=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin;

Comment: Sorry, I am at a loss as to what could be going wrong.